# How to iterate complete array of hashes in ruby - only first is retrieved

Tags: ruby, cfndsl

I have a cfndsl cloudformation template and a yaml file with input values. When i am trying to generate cloudformation, surprisingly only first value element of array (of hash) is getting generated.

What am i doing wrong?

I have tried changing various section of yaml file and the cfndsl code format but still getting only first block.

My Yaml file has hash as follows

```
SecurityGroupIngresss:
  - FromPort: 11211
    IpProtocol: 'tcp'
    CidrIp: '10.244.17.0/24'
    ToPort: 11211
  - FromPort: 11211
    IpProtocol: 'tcp'
    CidrIp: '10.244.18.0/24'
    ToPort: 11211
  - FromPort: 11211
    IpProtocol: 'tcp'
    CidrIp: '10.244.19.0/24'
    ToPort: 11211
  - FromPort: 11211
    IpProtocol: 'tcp'
    CidrIp: '10.244.16.0/21'
    ToPort: 11211
```

and cfndsl file has following section

```
    securityGroupIngresss.each do |securityGroupIngress|
      if !securityGroupIngress.nil?
        Resource(:SecurityGroupIngress) do
          Type('AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress')
          Property('Description', FnJoin(' ', ['Security Ingress for MemCache Stack', Ref('AWS::StackName')]))
          securityGroupIngress.each do |key,value|
            Property("#{key}", "#{value}")
          end            
          Property('GroupId', Ref('SecurityGroup'))
        end
      end
    end
```

Only getting one block of code which is as below:

```
    "SecurityGroupIngress": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            " ",
            [
              "Security Ingress for MemCache Stack",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "FromPort": "11211",
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "CidrIp": "10.244.17.0/24",
        "ToPort": "11211",
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
        }
      }
    },
```

Update: In CFNDSL I am fetching **securityGroupIngresss** variable as:

```
securityGroupIngresss = external_parameters.fetch(:SecurityGroupIngresss)
```

Ref [here](https://github.com/cfndsl/cfndsl#command-line-options)

Comment: What is `securityGroupIngresss`? I assume something like `YAML.load(File.read('/path/to/yaml.yml')).fetch('SecurityGroupIngresss')`

Comment: Check the array you are loading as per @3limin4t0r comment. Maybe add it to the question.

Comment: Hi @3limin4t0r I have updated my question above. I have fetched this variable using external_parameter clause as in link given.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to solve this. I Changed code as follows:

```
securityGroupIngresss = external_parameters.fetch(:SecurityGroupIngresss, {})
```

and

```
    securityGroupIngresss.each_with_index do |securityGroupIngress, index|
      if !securityGroupIngress.nil?
        EC2_SecurityGroupIngress(name.capitalize + 'Ingress' + "#{index}") do
          securityGroupIngress.each do |key, val|
            Property("#{key}", "#{val}")
          end
          Property('GroupId', Ref('SecurityGroup'))
        end
      end
    end
```

Now CFNDSL generates code for all blocks of my input. Thanks everyone.